# Remove selection of option using onmouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I wnant to remove selection without removing option. The code looks like this:

```
<select name="slovn" id="slovn_id" size="4" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;">
<option value="1" id="asd">item 1</option>
</select>
```

If I added in HTML a link:

```
<div>  
 <a href="#" class="remove">Remove selection</a>  
 </div>
```

And use jQuery all works:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){    
  $(this).parent().prev().find('option:selected').prop("selected",null);
});
```

But how to make without link? Only click on option or on outside area?
In the "item 1" from json a link is loaded. I need click on the option, open the link and remove selection after it, that is was possible click again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this working [jsfiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/YjQEM/1/) which will help you to get your requirement.

```
$("#slovn_id").change(function() {
    var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    alert(selectedIndex);
    this.selectedIndex = -1;
});​
```

**EDIT:**

As per your comments, made changes in fiddle. Hope, this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YjQEM/5/) will help you.

Comment: No, it's doesn't work. I use jstree. When I moving on the tree and click on the node the dialog window is opend (this `<select name="slovn" id="slovn_id" size="4" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;">
<option value="1" id="asd">item 1</option>
</select>`is in dialog) when I use your code the tree isn't load =(

Comment: I play with code location in script. As a selection it is works (the 1st your answer)but, the link wich tied to the option doesn't open. See it is a code wich parse the json and generate links - `
Add a value in option from the json
...options +='<option value="
$('#document').append(options); 
$(function(){// bind change event to select
$('#document').bind('change',function ()
{var url = $(this).val(); //get selected value
if (url) { // require a URL
window.open(url,'_blank'); //redirect
}return false;
});});` 
It's seems, that selection moved before the link was generated. What do you think?

Comment: You mean, you tied the link with option and when the option is selected, that link need to open in new tab and also selected value will reset. Am i right?

Comment: Yes) Now the link is open in new tab, but option is still selected and I don't click on it and open the link again.

Comment: I don't understand where I can use it in my code. I past it that way, but the link doesn't open
`$(function(){// bind change event to select
$('#links').bind('change', function () 
{var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
if (url) { // require a URL
        $(".asd").click(function() {
         window.open(url,'_blank'); // redirect          });}
return false; });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){ 
    $.each('option:selected',function(){
        $(this).attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
    });
});
```